# Remove recurrent (overlapping) slashes from string

Tags: python, string, split, overlapping

I m parsing URLS like this

```
>>> from urllib.parse import urlparse
>>> urlparse('http://foo.bar/path/to/heaven')
ParseResult(scheme='http', netloc='foo.bar', path='/path/to/heaven', params='', query='', fragment='')
```

Suppose I have an URL that has a malformed path with recurrent `/` like this:

```
>>> x = urlparse('http://foo.bar/path/to/////foo///baz//bar'))
ParseResult(scheme='http', netloc='foo.bar', path='/path/to/////foo///baz//bar', params='', query='', fragment='')
```

As you can see, the `x.path` still contain recurrent slashes, I'm trying to remove them so I have tried split and looping and replacing like this:

```
>>> newpath = x.path.split('/')
['', 'path', 'to', '', '', '', '', 'foo', '', '', 'baz', '', 'bar']
>>> for i in newpath:
    if i == '':
        newpath.remove('')
>>> '/'.join(newpath)
'/path/to/foo/baz/bar'
```

Which gives the desired output but i think this solution is inefficient and trash. How can I do it better?

Comment: Did you try a regular expression approach?

Comment: @jsb No, I read about regex being slow and should be avoided at most, thats why i haven't thought of using them

Comment: Regular expressions being slow is probably not true.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what regular expressions are made for:

```
import regex as re

url = "http://foo.bar/path/to/////foo///baz//bar"

rx = re.compile(r'(?:(?:http|ftp)s?://)(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|/+')
url = rx.sub('/', url)
print(url)
```

This yields

```
http://foo.bar/path/to/foo/baz/bar
```

See [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/kMq8cM/1). The only real problem is to leave any double forward slashes in the protocol as they are, hence the newer `regex` module and `(*SKIP)(*FAIL)`. You could achieve the same functionality with lookbehinds in the `re` module.

Comment: do you think this way is faster than @barmar list comprehension answer or its negligible performance for millions of urls?

Answer (score 0):

```
import re

s = 'http://foo.bar/path/to/////foo///baz//bar'

s = re.sub(r'(?<!:)/{2,}', '/', s)
print(s)
```

Prints:

```
http://foo.bar/path/to/foo/baz/bar
```

---

EDIT: Compiling regex:

```
import re

s = 'http://foo.bar/path/to/////foo///baz//bar'
r = re.compile(r'(?<!:)/{2,}')

s = r.sub('/', s)
print(s)
```

Comment: do you think this way is faster than @barmar list comprehension and Jan regex answer or its negligible performance for millions of urls?

Comment: @tofu Only way is to test it. But compile the regex before-hand to speed things up (see my edit.)

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't modify a list that you're iterating over. See [strange result when removing item from a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6260089/strange-result-when-removing-item-from-a-list)

You can use a list comprehension to create a list without all the `''` elements.

```
newpath = [s in x.path.split('/') if s != '']
'/'.join(newpath)
```

Comment: do you think this way is faster than regex or its negligible performance for millions of urls?